# How does one escape characters in Delphi string

Tags: delphi, string, escaping, literals

Delphi strings use single quotes, for example '`a valid string`'. How does one specify the `'` character within a literal string? How would one refer to the null byte (Unicode code point `U+0000`)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To add a single quote to a string, you include two `'` marks e.g.

```
str := '''test string''';
Writeln(str)
```

In the string above, you have the normal single quotation to start a string and then two for the single quote. Same goes for the end of the string.

You can also use `#` followed by a number for other escape character e.g.
For a new line:

```
str := 'Newline' + #13 + #10
```

or just

```
str := 'Newline'#13#10
```

Of course, using the platform-dependent constant for newline is better.

Comment: The only issue with the #13#10 is that the compiler will generate a warning if the +'s are missing.  It will compile and run fine, but with warnings.

Comment: When did the compiler start issuing warnings about that? I know it didn't do that in Delphi 5, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't do that Delphi 2005. What warning does it print now?

Comment: I think `QuotedStr` / `AnsiQuotedStr` are worth mentioning. Especially useful when quoting variables, e.g. `showMessage('param value is ' + QuotedStr(param))`

Answer (score 15):

To answer the last part of the question, you can use

```
#$0000
```

To add U+0000

This way you can add the other Unicode chars too. (Be sure to use a font that can display those characters.)

Comment: You can also use `#0` instead.

Answer (score 10):

For `'` character put it twice. For example: `'Don''t'`. Null byte type as #0.