# Using quote inside strings in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, escaping, quotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one escape characters in Delphi string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302409/how-does-one-escape-characters-in-delphi-string)

In Delphi a string is contained within a pair of `'` but I need to use `'` in my string...
and when I use one it brings a end to the entire string identification.

```
'inside string ' but this bit is outside' inside again' and the end
```

Is there some symbol that removes the coding affect of the next character?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need another quote to escape a quote:

```
Writeln('I''m in your head'); //prints: I'm in your head
Writeln(''''); //prints: '
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302409/how-does-one-escape-characters-in-delphi-string).

Answer (score 17):

Delphi has `QuotedStr()` function that adds quotes around string and does escaping of apostrophes in string automatically.

```
procedure MyForm.MyProc;
var str : string;
begin
  str = QuotedStr(MyForm.Edit1);
  ...
end;
```

`QuotedStr()` will put contents of edit field into apostrophes. If edit field contains apostrophes, they will be properly escaped.

Answer (score 5):

Similar Question here:

[How does one escape characters in Delphi string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302409/how-does-one-escape-characters-in-delphi-string/302431#302431)

Covers single quotes and escape characters

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `QuotedStr` function to fix strings with quotes in them.  Also, I often find it helpful to have defined constants like `CRLF` and `TAB` that represent `#13#10` and `#9` respectively.  Sometimes, it seems clearer (to me at least) to do something similar with quotes.