# Delphi & SQLite: Get the records count per month for the last 12 months

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firemonkey, firedac

I'm trying to get the number of record grouped by month for the last 12 months including the current month.
Not from the beginning of the current year.

I have a table EVENTS and a field WODATE. I can do this

```
  aFDQuery.Connection := TrackingDBConnection;
  aFDQuery.SQL.Clear;
  with aFDQuery.SQL do
    begin
      BeginUpdate;
      try
        Add('Select MONTH(MAX(WODate)) AS month, COUNT(*) AS count ');
        Add('from events where YEAR(WODATE) = 2020 ');
        Add('GROUP BY YEAR(WODate), MONTH(WODate) ORDER BY YEAR(WODate), MONTH(WODate) ASC');
      finally
        EndUpdate;
      end;
```

With that query, I get a result only for months where there are values other than 0 and obviously only for 2020

But I would like to get the last 12 months from now even with 0 like this

```
[01]    11/2019     12 
[02]    12/2019     24 
[03]    01/2020      0 
[04]    02/2020     12
[05]    03/2020     44
[06]    04/2020      0
[07]    05/2020     21
[08]    06/2020     37
[09]    07/2020      0
[10]    08/2020     15 
[11]    09/2020     45 
[12]    10/2020      6
```

I have tried this but I get a Syntax error

```
Add('from EVENTS where WODATE >= DATE(NOW, -12 month) ');

ESQLiteNativeException: [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: near "month": syntax error
```

Is it possible ? Thank you in advance for any suggestion

With the answer from Peter (See below), I get this

```
2019-11-01 - 2019-11-30    0
2019-12-01 - 2019-12-31    0
2020-01-01 - 2020-01-31    0
2020-02-01 - 2020-02-29    0
2020-03-01 - 2020-03-31    0
2020-04-01 - 2020-04-30    0
2020-05-01 - 2020-05-31    0
2020-06-01 - 2020-06-30    0
2020-07-01 - 2020-07-31    0
2020-08-01 - 2020-08-31    0
2020-09-01 - 2020-09-30    0
2020-10-01 - 2020-10-31   13
```

Which is perfect
Thanks a lot Peter. You deserve a belgian beer

Comment: Could you make a SQLite database file example available somewhere so that I can experiment request with your data?

Comment: Please add the syntax error you get to your question.

Comment: Missing coma before "month"?

Comment: Hi François. I don't have such amount of data yet. Just building the queries for the Dashboard. But I can quickly build a sample db with fake data. Where / How to send that to you ? Email ?

Comment: You can send it by email (You'll find my email easily searching on Google), but better to make it available on a download site so that other may test as well.

Comment: With comma before month, I get :  ESQLiteNativeException:  [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: no such column: NOW

Comment: What version of SQLite do you use? Since 3.8.3 you can use CTE and VALUES clause. `SELECT sqlite_version()`

Comment: As Peter Wolf said, values could be the way to go. For Example union join a fixed Number of Dataset into your Data. For Example for every first in Month one extra value with the SQL Command VALUES, and than taking your count -1 to get the correct value.

Comment: Test file here https://gofile.io/d/409yOO

Comment: I am using 3.31.1

Comment: Your test database has not even a format compatible with the request you gave :-(

Comment: `now`, `start of monts`, etc must be enclosed in single quotes in SQL text - as in my answer. Use two single quotes in string literal as an escape sequence for single quote, e.g.: `Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-11 month''), date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-10 month'', ''-1 day'')), ');`. See [How does one escape characters in Delphi string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302409/how-does-one-escape-characters-in-delphi-string).

Comment: Using `Format` and `QuotedStr` functions you just overcomplicate the things. You only need to use two quotes instead of one in SQL text. I added the Delphi snippet at the end of my answer. Besides you use spaces to align values in SQL text (e.g. `' -9 month'`), but that's causing issues with SQLite `date` function which doesn't expect space there and produces some `NULL` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't much a Delphi question but rather SQLite question. Since [version 3.8.3](https://sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_3) you can use [common table expressions](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) (CTE) and the [`VALUES` clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#values). Below I'm going to explain how.

First you can construct static date ranges table with 12 entries, where each entry represents a single month from past 12 months including the current:

```sql
VALUES
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-11 month'), date('now', 'start of month', '-10 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-10 month'), date('now', 'start of month', '-9 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-9 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-8 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-8 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-7 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-7 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-6 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-6 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-5 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-5 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-4 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-4 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-3 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-3 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-2 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-2 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-1 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-1 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month'),              date('now', 'start of month', '+1 month', '-1 day'))
```

This gives (as of current date):

| StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-11-01 | 2019-11-30 |
| 2019-12-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31 |
| 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-29 |
| 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-31 |
| 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-30 |
| 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-31 |
| 2020-06-01 | 2020-06-30 |
| 2020-07-01 | 2020-07-31 |
| 2020-08-01 | 2020-08-31 |
| 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-30 |
| 2020-10-01 | 2020-10-31 |

Using a CTE you can join your `events` table to the above list:

```sql
WITH DateRanges(StartDate, EndDate) AS (VALUES
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-11 month'), date('now', 'start of month', '-10 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-10 month'), date('now', 'start of month', '-9 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-9 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-8 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-8 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-7 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-7 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-6 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-6 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-5 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-5 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-4 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-4 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-3 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-3 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-2 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-2 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-1 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-1 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month'),              date('now', 'start of month', '+1 month', '-1 day'))
)
SELECT
  DateRanges.StartDate,
  DateRanges.EndDate,
  COUNT(Events.ROWID) AS Count
FROM DateRanges
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Events ON (DateRanges.StartDate <= Events.WODate) AND (Events.WODate <= DateRanges.EndDate)
GROUP BY
  DateRanges.StartDate, DateRanges.EndDate
ORDER BY
  DateRanges.StartDate
```

See [sample SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d0318/1).

### Edit

I see that you're struggling to execute the SQL using `TFDQuery`, so I did it for you:

```
with aFDQuery.SQL do
begin
  BeginUpdate;
  try
    Add('WITH DateRanges(StartDate, EndDate) AS (VALUES');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-11 month''), date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-10 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-10 month''), date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-9 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-9 month''),  date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-8 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-8 month''),  date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-7 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-7 month''),  date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-6 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-6 month''),  date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-5 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-5 month''),  date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-4 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-4 month''),  date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-3 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-3 month''),  date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-2 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-2 month''),  date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-1 month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-1 month''),  date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''-1 day'')),');
    Add('(date(''now'', ''start of month''),              date(''now'', ''start of month'', ''+1 month'', ''-1 day'')))');
    Add('SELECT DateRanges.StartDate, DateRanges.EndDate, COUNT(Events.ROWID) AS Count');
    Add('FROM DateRanges LEFT OUTER JOIN Events ON (DateRanges.StartDate <= Events.WODate) AND (Events.WODate <= DateRanges.EndDate)');
    Add('GROUP BY DateRanges.StartDate, DateRanges.EndDate');
    Add('ORDER BY DateRanges.StartDate');
  finally
    EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. I am struggling a lot with SQL syntax. Thanks a lot for your help. Your code is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

User Peter Wolf answer I designed this small modification answering - IMO - better the question:

```
WITH DateRanges(StartDate, EndDate) AS (VALUES
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-11 month'), date('now', 'start of month', '-10 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-10 month'), date('now', 'start of month', '-9 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-9 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-8 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-8 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-7 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-7 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-6 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-6 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-5 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-5 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-4 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-4 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-3 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-3 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-2 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-2 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-1 month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month', '-1 month'),  date('now', 'start of month', '-1 day')),
  (date('now', 'start of month'),              date('now', 'start of month', '+1 month', '-1 day'))
)
SELECT
  strftime('%m/%Y', DateRanges.StartDate) as Month,
  COUNT(Events.ROWID) AS Count
FROM DateRanges
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Events ON (DateRanges.StartDate <= Date(Events.WODate)) AND (Events.WODate <= Date(DateRanges.EndDate))
GROUP BY
  DateRanges.StartDate, DateRanges.EndDate
ORDER BY
  DateRanges.StartDate
```